# How to use generics with @SuperBuilder to common logic to a base class builder?

Tags: java, generics, lombok

I have 2 DTOs that share common base - typical inheritance. I also want to use builder pattern, so Lombok's @SuperBuilder comes to the rescue. Now I want to apply common logic to the "common" part of builders.

I am able to do it with casting, but I don't know how to keep it typesafe using generics.

Using following (runnable) example, how to define generics in `commonize` method so that `testGeneric` will work and stop yelding compilation errors?

```
    public class Example {
        static <C extends Base, BUILDER extends Base.BaseBuilder<C, BUILDER>> BUILDER commonize(BUILDER builder) {
            return builder.someName("commonName");
        }
        static < BUILDER extends Base.BaseBuilder> BUILDER rawComminize(BUILDER builder) {
            return (BUILDER)builder.someName("commonName");
        }
    
        static void testGeneric(){
            //that yelds compilation errors - how to fix it?
            Foo foo = commonize(Foo.builder()).fooProp("foo?").build();
            Bar bar = commonize(Bar.builder()).barProp("bar?").build();
            System.out.println(foo);
            System.out.println(bar);
        }
        static void testCasts(){
            //thats fine and works as expected - but not strictly type safe
            Foo foo = rawComminize(Foo.builder()).fooProp("foo?").build();
            Bar bar = rawComminize(Bar.builder()).barProp("bar?").build();
            System.out.println(foo);
            System.out.println(bar);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            testGeneric();
            testCasts();
        }
    }
    
    @SuperBuilder
    @ToString
    class Base {
        String someName;
    }
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    @SuperBuilder
    class Foo extends Base {
        String fooProp;
    }
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    @SuperBuilder
    class Bar extends Base {
        String barProp;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it will work in this setup. Lombok uses wildcards for `builder()` which would require casts anyway and generics have no inheritance: [Is List a subclass of List? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I guess this is acceptable statement that it "cannot be done". I did delombok builders to see what is the actual implementation before, but didnt think that wildcards there will couse me the problems.

Comment: You can put your comment as an answer, so I can upvote propertly if you would like.

Comment: Give this question a bit of time, maybe someone will find a way or can suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a tricky one, but you nearly had it. This is way to go:

```
public static <B extends BUILDER, BUILDER extends Base.BaseBuilder<?, B>> BUILDER commonize(BUILDER builder) {
    return builder.someName("commonName");
}
```

If you are feeling jaunty today, you may even go further with `@ExtensionMethod`:

```
@ExtensionMethod({ Extensions.class })
public class Example {
    static void testGeneric() {
        Foo foo = Foo.builder().commonize().fooProp("foo?").build();
        Bar bar = Bar.builder().commonize().barProp("foo?").build();
        System.out.println(foo);
        System.out.println(bar);
    }
}

class Extensions {
    public static <B extends BUILDER, BUILDER extends Base.BaseBuilder<?, B>> BUILDER commonize(BUILDER builder) {
        return builder.someName("commonName");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does infact allows code to compile, but I still have a warining regarding unchecked cast `Unchecked assignment: '? extends BUILDER' to 'BUILDER'`. Any wy to overcome that now?

Comment: Also it can be right away  `commonize(BUILDER obj)` in your example so the signature is less scary.

Comment: `<C extends BUILDER, BUILDER extends Base.BaseBuilder<?, C>>` removes the warning and still works!. No idea why.... ON the other hand its now `Type parameter 'C' hides visible type 'org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.C'` so i guess I have traded 1 warning to another.

Comment: Hmm, I neither get that warning in Eclipse nor with javac. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I use javac JDK11

Comment: Same here, no warning. There must be something slightly different between this example and your actual code. BTW: The "'C' hides" warning can be simply removed by using something else than "C", like "CL".

Comment: I will try it out on my PC when Ill be back home. Cannot post images from coprorate network;)